# Slider First image Fix Width

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

At my home page in slider code i want to fix width for first image. Is it possible from css or html. Because i tried but not work. My current slider css code are bellow.

```
#slider {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Slider_bg.png");
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner, .wrapper {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: 0;
}

ul.kwicks {
    background-color: #333333;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

ul.kwicks li {
    background: url("../images/icons/ajax_loader.gif") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% transparent;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

.kw_img {
    display: block;
}

.kw_img img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.kw_shadow {
    background: url("../images/icons/overlay.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.last .kw_shadow {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
    border-right: 0 none;
}
```

My current Slider HTML Code Bellow.

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="inner">
    <ul style="width:960px; height:400px; margin:15px 0;" data-width="960" data-max="660" class="kwicks" id="kwicks-1">
        <li class="kwick" style="left: 0px; width: 192px; margin: 0px; position: absolute;">
            <div class="kw_shadow"></div>
            <div class="kw_img">
                <img width="960" height="400" alt="" src="http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/themes/cstardesign/cache/timthumb.php?src=http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/2.jpg&amp;h=400&amp;w=960&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="kwick" style="left: 192px; width: 192px; margin: 0px; position: absolute;">
            <div class="kw_shadow"></div>
            <div class="kw_img">
                <img width="960" height="400" alt="" src="http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/themes/cstardesign/cache/timthumb.php?src=http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Image-2.jpg&amp;h=400&amp;w=960&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="kwick" style="left: 384px; width: 192px; margin: 0px; position: absolute;">
        <div class="kw_shadow"></div>
        <div class="kw_img">
                <img width="960" height="400" alt="" src="http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/themes/cstardesign/cache/timthumb.php?src=http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/3.png&amp;h=400&amp;w=960&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="kwick" style="left: 576px; width: 192px; margin: 0px; position: absolute;">
        <div class="kw_shadow"></div>
        <div class="kw_img">
                <img width="960" height="400" alt="" src="http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/themes/cstardesign/cache/timthumb.php?src=http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Image-1.jpg&amp;h=400&amp;w=960&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100">
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="kwick last" style="right: 0px; width: 192px; margin: 0px; position: absolute;">
        <div class="kw_shadow"></div>
        <div class="kw_img"><img width="960" height="400" alt="" src="http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/themes/cstardesign/cache/timthumb.php?src=http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/1.jpg&amp;h=400&amp;w=960&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

​

Currently my slider looking like this. http://silverharmony.in/

And i actual want to like below link.

http://silverharmony.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/slider-screenshoot.png

Comment: are you using any plugins for this work?? did you check its default options or settings or config??

Comment: I am not using any plugin. Its by default in my theme. Its name "cstar WP Theme" i was buy from theme forest website. I check all, but there are no option for this. http://themeforest.net/item/cstar-design-wordpress-theme/2490278

Answer (score 1):

Slider is using [Kwicks](http://devsmash.com/projects/kwicks) jQuery plugin. I added first `li` item `.kwicks-selected` class to achive what you are looking for.

Example here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/dkx4t/3/)